# Can't click on <li> or <a> elements, browser displays them though

Tags: html, css, padding

I have this strange thing happening to my code. Using Firefox or Chrome (tried these two only) I cannot click (or even select with mouse) all of my categories in my website. The browser totally ignores them, but it shows them though.

You can see the code in the source code too, and looks OK. I don't know what I did wrong, but I doubt it's a server-side problem, it has something to do with the CSS, because when I removed a `padding` line from the CSS (from `ul.menu li` exactly), one of the categories suddenly became clickable/selectable again (*Sample Category 4*). I never encountered something like this in the past and I can't think of a way to fix it. I'm not a very good stylist.

Here is the URL: ~removed~

You can see the problem in the "RULES SECTIONS" in the right, *Sample Category 4* and *Sample Category 5* are the unclickable/unselectable categories.

Ideas?

Comment: these are clickable & selectable

Comment: Works in IE9, but not Firefox 16.0.1

Comment: I don't see anything in that page misbehaving. The links are clickable, the text is selectable.

Comment: If they were I wouldn't be asking this question, would I? Try it using Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: i can see in last li that you have applied class="last".wat styles you have applied in that class.

Comment: In the CSS for #container, change `padding-right: 220px` to be `margin-right: 260px`. Changing the z-index could lead to items being displayed under your menu, which can look odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your #container is overlapping the menu on the right. Add this to .mini-panel in the css (line 4020 in style.php) position:relative; z-index:1000;

That should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your CSS i your #container.

You have the following CSS

```
#container {
    padding-right: 220px;
    position: relative;
}
```

You need to change the padding to a margin, because the padding fill the whole space and the element is then positioned over your last two links. That is the reason that they are not selectable.

Change to

```
#container {
    margin-right: 260px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Agree; with the caveat that margin-right: 260px; is the optimum value as this is the width of the menu it currently covers.

Comment: that might be right, I have not looked for the exact pixel sizes.

Comment: @dash ok I followed it up, you are right 260px is the right amount, I have edited my value

Answer (score 1):

They're all sat underneath your container div. Try using [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to put it to the back or design your page such that your div's don't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Container div is overlapping to the right menu. so set following CSS:

```
.mini-panel{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   width: 200px;
}
```

OR you can reduce width of #container.

Answer (score 1):

go in your css and edit the element:

```
#container {
    padding-right: 220px;
    position: relative;
}
```

turning it into:

```
#container {
    margin-right: 260px;
    position: relative;
}
```